# How to bind a viewmodel method in layout and pass a dynamic value to the viewmodel method

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, android-mvvm

How to bind a ViewModel method in layout and pass a dynamic value to the ViewModel method

1. ViewModel

```
suspend fun get_Organizations(
    username: String
) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.get_organizations(username) }
```

2. Layout

```
    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.hopelastrestart.ui.home.organization.OrganizationViewModel"
            />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:text=""

            android:text="@{(viewmodel.user.name)-> viewmodel.get_Organizations()"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the username serves as the parameter, I think you're looking for:

```
android:text="@{()-> viewmodel.get_Organizations(viewmodel.user.name)}"
```

However, this isn't sufficient in itself because `get_Organizations()` is a suspension function. In general, suspension functions should not be exposed but, instead, managed internally by some coroutine (usually from the `viewModelScope`). In the case the username is immutable, this could be achieved by a coroutine block during the view model's init. I assume you are already using some sort of dependency injection or view model factory to provide the view model with the appropriate username.

```
class SomeViewModel(username: String) : ViewModel() {

    private val _organizationsText: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val organizationsText: LiveData<String> = _organizationsText

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _organizationsText.value = repository.get_Organizations(username)
        }
    }

}
```

In this case, the data binding could be achieved without the use of a lambda:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.organizationsText}"
```

If the username is mutable, you'd be looking for something a bit more complex. Regardless, I would encourage you to refactor this via a LiveData transformation, a Kotlin Flow, or some other reactive framework. When the view model is already aware of the username, it shouldn't need to be passed into the `getOrganizations()` function because it's already available. If `get_Organizations()` must remain public, this could be achieved through a private, overloaded function. I am happy to elaborate given more context. There's quite little I could glean of your scenario based on the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, To explain the context more clearly, I have a login activity(activity1), upon succesfull login another activity(activity2) is launched, activity2 view model has a function that accepts username and returns all organizations associated with user. I want to invoke the Viewmodel function from the layoutfile and also pass the username from layout file.